# How to install ibm_db_dbi module in python3.6 docker image?

Tags: python, docker, python-3.6

I have successfully installed `ibm_db v3.0.1` package in docker image but when i am trying to import ibm_db_dbi module it throw the error.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

WORKDIR /run

COPY . /run

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 7000

CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

after build its successfully executed the below ibm_db module to image.

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/cb/f77d9bd5f64246074af364cc30e20e3044c533890f3b67d30e89615c2fc5/ibm_db-3.0.1.tar.gz (642kB)

Please help me resolve this issue.

```
command to run docker image :-  docker run -it -p 7000:7000  dotsapi
```

> error while running the docker file:-
>
> File "/run/Informix_Conn.py", line 3, in
>
> ```
> import ibm_db_dbi as db ImportError: Error loading shared library libcrypt.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the actual text of the `Dockerfile` you're running and the specific error message you're getting?  If it's an error while running the container, also a minimal excerpt from the Python script and the `docker run` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `pip install ibm_db` in your dockerfile or create a requirements.txt file.
And call him in your dockerfile with :

```
 ADD        ./requirements.txt ./
 RUN        python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

EDIT
It worked for me :
In my dockerfile :

```
FROM       python:3.6
ADD        ./requirements.txt ./
RUN        python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD        ./test.py /run
```

After building succesfully I ran my image with

```
docker run --name testpython testpython:1 sleep 3600
```

Go in my container

```
docker exec -it testpython /bin/bash
```

And when I run a python console or my test script, the import is OK.

NOTE : 
With the image python:3.6.8-alpine3.9 the build doesn't work.
[Check this to see why](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/418)

Comment: I have already installed ibm_db package successfully but issue still persist.

Comment: Try to run your script with a python3 command. Be sure that your lib is install in python3 and not python2. You can go inside your container with a docker exec -it to verify that.

Comment: I run the script using python3 command but still the issue persist

Comment: ok, try to use pip3 for install your lib. I will try on my side

Comment: tried using pip3.6 to install lib but still same issue.

Comment: No problem ;) and sorry for my approximately english