# Unable to find libcrypt.so.1 while importing ibm_db

Tags: python-3.x, docker, db2

I am getting following traceback while importing ibm_db in python -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/working/Script.py", line 5, in <module>
import ibm_db
ImportError: Error loading shared library libcrypt.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1)
```

Please find below my docker image and requirements.txt file -

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.16

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies python3 py-pip openssl ca-certificates py-openssl wget libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev py-pip py3-pandas build-base \
  && apk add python3 make g++ \
  && pip install --upgrade pip \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && apk del build-dependencies

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "Script.py" ]
```

Requirements.txt -

```
cryptography==2.9
botocore==1.12.253
azure-storage-blob==2.1.0
azure-storage-common==2.1.0
snowflake-connector-python==1.9.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
ibm_db
s3fs
```

Comment: I think you're hitting one of the limitations of the Alpine-based image.  [How to install ibm_db_dbi module in python3.6 docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744178/how-to-install-ibm-db-dbi-module-in-python3-6-docker-image) suggests switching to a Debian-based image, which has the more common GNU libc; does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

The IBM clidriver (on which the python ibm_db module depends) is not supported on Alpine-Linux - that is to say, it will not work on Alpine-Linux.

That driver (clidriver) is closed source, and for Linux x64 is built with gcc.

You must choose a supported base Linux , Ubuntu, Red Hat, SuSe.